# Gson Java - Child class from JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an abstract class for configuration files, which can be extended by lots of other classes. I managed to get the system working for writing it to JSON, but now I need the load function.

Here's the general Configuration class:

```
public class Configuration {

    public boolean load(){
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".json");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.fromJson(reader, this.getClass());
        reader.close();
        /** Doesn't give an error, but doesn't set any info to the child class */
    }

    public boolean save(){
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".json");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.toJson(this, writer);
        writer.close();
        /** This all works fine. */
    }

}
```

Here's an example of an extending class:

```
public class ExampleConfig extends Configuration {

    private static transient ExampleConfig i = new ExampleConfig();
    public static ExampleConfig get() { return i; }

    @Expose public String ServerID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

}
```

In my main class I would do:

```
ExampleConfig.get().load();
System.out.println(ExampleConfig.get().ServerID);
```

This does not give any errors, but neither is the class loaded from the JSON. It keeps outputting a random UUID even though I want to load one from the JSON file. I'm probably getting the wrong instance of the child class, but I'm out of ideas on how to fix this. (Using `this` in `gson.fromJson(.....);` does not work.

Comment: `gson.fromJson(reader, this.getClass());` -- this is where your value is lost. The `fromJson` method returns a _new_ value that you have to assign somewhere.

Comment: Makes sense, how would I do this with my current example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to assign a read value to your configuration instance. Java cannot support anything like `this = gson.fromJson(...)`, and Gson can only return  *new* values and cannot patch existing ones. The below is a sort of Gson hack, and please only use it if it's really a *must* for you. Again, I would strongly recommend you to redesign your code and separate your configuration objects and configuration readers/writers -- these are just two different things that conflict from the technical perspective. As a result of refactoring, you could have, let's say, once you get an instance of your configuration, just delegate it to a writer to persist it elsewhere. If you need it back, then just get an instance of a reader, read the configuration value and assign it to your configuration (configurations are singletons, I remember), like:

```java
final ConfigurationWriter writer = getConfigurationWriter();
writer.write(ExampleConfig.get());
...
final ConfigurationReader reader = getConfigurationReader();
ExampleConfig.set(reader.read(ExampleConfig.class));
```

At least this code does not mix two different things, and makes the result of `reader.read` be *explicitly* read and assigned to your configuration singleton.

If you're fine to open the gate of evil and make your code work because of hacks, then you could use Gson `TypeAdapterFactory` in order to cheat Gson and *patch the current configuration instance*.

```java
abstract class Configuration {

    private static final Gson saveGson = new Gson();

    public final void load()
            throws IOException {
        try ( final FileReader reader = new FileReader(getTargetName()) ) {
            // You have to instantiate Gson every time (unless you use caching strategies) in order to let it be *specifically* be aware of the current
            // Configuration instance class. Thus you cannot make it a static field.
            final Gson loadGson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
                        // A Gson way to denote a type since Configuration.class may not be enough and it also works with generics
                        private final TypeToken<Configuration> configurationTypeToken = new TypeToken<Configuration>() {
                        };

                        @Override
                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // isAssignableFrom is deprecated
                        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                            // Checking if the type token represents a parent class for the given configuration
                            // If yes, then we cheat...
                            if ( configurationTypeToken.isAssignableFrom(typeToken) ) {
                                // The map that's artificially bound as great cheating to a current configuration instance
                                final Map<Type, InstanceCreator<?>> instanceCreators = bindInstance(typeToken.getType(), Configuration.this);
                                // A factory used by Gson internally, we're intruding into its heart
                                final ConstructorConstructor constructorConstructor = new ConstructorConstructor(instanceCreators);
                                final TypeAdapterFactory delegatedTypeAdapterFactory = new ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory(
                                        constructorConstructor,
                                        gson.fieldNamingStrategy(),
                                        gson.excluder(),
                                        new JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory(constructorConstructor)
                                );
                                // Since the only thing necessary here is to define how to instantiate an object
                                // (and we just give it an already-existing instance)
                                // ... just delegate the job to Gson -- it would think as if it's creating a new instance.
                                // Actually it won't create one, but would "patch" the current instance
                                return delegatedTypeAdapterFactory.create(gson, typeToken);
                            }
                            // Otherwise returning a null means looking up for an existing type adapter from how Gson is configured
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
            // The value is still loaded to nowhere, however.
            // The type adapter factory is tightly bound to an existing configuration instance via ConstructorConstructor
            // This is actually another code smell...
            loadGson.fromJson(reader, getClass());
        }
    }

    public final void save()
            throws IOException {
        try ( final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(getTargetName()) ) {
            saveGson.toJson(this, writer);
        }
    }

    private String getTargetName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + ".json";
    }

    private static Map<Type, InstanceCreator<?>> bindInstance(final Type type, final Configuration existingConfiguration) {
        return singletonMap(type, new InstanceCreator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object createInstance(final Type t) {
                return t.equals(type) ? existingConfiguration : null; // don't know if null is allowed here though
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I hope that the comments in the code above are exhaustive. As I said above, I doubt that you need it just because of intention to have a bit nicer code. You could argue that `java.util.Properties` can load and save itself. Yes, that's true, but `java.util.Properties` is open to iterate over its properties by design and it can always read and write properties from elsewhere to anywhere. Gson uses reflection, a method of peeking the fields under the hood, and this is awesome for well-designed objects. You need some refactoring and separate two concepts: the data and data writer/reader.